# light admin configuration with spring

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, hibernate-entitymanager, lightadmin

I wanted to use light admin with spring boot.
My project is working fine intially but when

when i am adding dependency into `pom.xml`

```
<lightadmin.version>1.2.0.RC1</lightadmin.version>
dependency>
    <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
    <version>${lightadmin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

it will throw error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/boot/configur
ation/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-b
eans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

other configuration files:

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bootExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

        <tomcat.version>8.0.15</tomcat.version>

        <lightadmin.version>1.2.0.RC1</lightadmin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
            <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
            <version>${lightadmin.version}</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->


        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- we want to rely on external log4j2 -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- Please change scope to "provided" for deploying as a web module to 
                servlet container -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!-- Please change scope to "provided" for deploying as a web module to 
                servlet container -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lightadmin-nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>lightadmin-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories> -->

</project>
```

### AppInitializer.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.boot.configuration" })
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AppInitializer{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AppInitializer.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's work with Boot:");
    }
}
```

### AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.boot")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/theme1/");
    }



    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

### HibernateConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.boot.model"});

       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

       return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to configure Hibernate by self if you can do it using Spring Boot `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

[Here is my github repo with configuration in `application.properties`](https://github.com/evelan/SpringBoot-demo)

You also need dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Pomykala: i am new to spring boot. but i didn't getting my configuration is working fine until i added light admin dependency. i removed dependancy and error just gone. so what is the problem.

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh Probably there is some dependency conflict, that's why i'm recommend to use built-in database configuration and get rid of you hibernate configuration especially if you are new :)

Comment: can it automatically reads database configurations from application.properties. if not where to configure

Comment: I tried as you said but it didn't work for me. again same error.